# formatting integers in pivot_table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The output of the following piece of code is

```
import numpy, random, pandas
random.seed(10000)

sz = 1000000
pd = pandas.DataFrame({"x":random.choices(range(2), k=sz), "y":random.choices(range(3), k=sz)})
pd["values"] = 1
pd.pivot_table(index="x", columns="y", aggfunc="count", margins=True)
```

shown below

```
       values                               
y           0         1         2        All
x                                           
0    166575.0  166726.0  166553.0   499854.0
1    166823.0  166366.0  166957.0   500146.0
All  333398.0  333092.0  333510.0  1000000.0
```

How can a format statement be added so that the counts print without the trailing .0.  I do not wish to do this using a `pandas.set_option` which may change the behavior for all dataframes in this session.

Comment: Do you think `pd.pivot_table(index="x", columns="y", aggfunc="count", margins=True).astype(int)` ?

Comment: That certainly works here.  Thank you.  Can you suggest an approach where I can do this by column?  Suppose I want to do this for columns 1 & 2 only?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), for remove `MultiIndex` from columns add parameter `values`:

```
df = (pd.pivot_table(index="x", 
                    columns="y", 
                    aggfunc="count", 
                    values='values',
                    margins=True)
        .astype(int))

print (df)
y         0       1       2      All
x                                   
0    166575  166726  166553   499854
1    166823  166366  166957   500146
All  333398  333092  333510  1000000
```

If want apply `astype` ony for some columns:

```
df = (pd.pivot_table(index="x", 
                    columns="y", 
                    aggfunc="count", 
                    values='values',
                    margins=True)

cols = [1,2]
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(int)

print (df)
            0       1       2        All
x                                       
0    166575.0  166726  166553   499854.0
1    166823.0  166366  166957   500146.0
All  333398.0  333092  333510  1000000.0
```